# How to put php code in to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I am using Joomla JEA component, and when click ad page. i need that the page would load in to the new window. How to do that ? Please help me

**here is code**

```
 <?php if ($imgUrl = $this->getFirstImageUrl($row)): ?>
      <dt class="image">
              <a onclick="myFunction()" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_jea&view=property&id='. $row->slug) ?>" title="<?php echo JText::_('COM_JEA_DETAIL') ?>"> 
              <img onclick="myFunction()" src="<?php echo $imgUrl ?>" alt="<?php echo JText::_('COM_JEA_DETAIL') ?>" /></a>
       </dt>
  <?php endif ?>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you run that code? Nothing happens? Have you viewed the DOM after load and see that all of your HTML is there?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the link from hidden variable.

```
<input type="hidden" id="mylink" value="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_jea&view=property&id='. $row->slug) ?>" />
```

Now use this value in your function.

```
function myFunction() {
    var url = document.getElementById('mylink').value;
    var myWindow = window.open(url, "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
}
```